# How to change the default `overwrite` behaviour on `DataFrame

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to overwrite the contents of a SQL table. Currently the behaviour of Spark is to delete the table and then create a new one, when I use the `overwrite`-mode. Due to restrictive permissions I am not able to do this. The current solution is to use another Python package to clean the table and then write the data-frame to the SQL-DB. Which seems wrong.

Is there a way to alter this behaviour?

See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=jdbc#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc) for the documentation of the used function.

```
# Usage example (current state)
# Pre: Clear table.
df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="baz", mode='overwrite, properties=properties)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just faced similar issue and it turns out that truncating the JDBC table is available since [Spark 2.1.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16463).

To enable truncation there is need to set `mode='overwrite'` and add additional key in properties:

```
properties['truncate'] = 'true'
df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="baz", mode='overwrite', properties=properties)
```